# Creating nodes in matrix (2)

Tags: matrices, nodes, columns, gauss

I asked a question before [but I redacted it wrong](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/418055/creating-nodes-in-matrix?noredirect=1#comment1046294_418055).
I needed to know how to move the nodes in that matrix. The nodes are currently on the right side, b I want to move them freely to show column operations as well. I cannot figure out from the code how to move them around.
Thank you!

EDIT: Everytime I copy the code it kind of agglutinates instead of aligning itself like in my document. Please find the link here instead:
https://www.sharelatex.com/read/djqkprqvrfys

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc,chains,matrix,shadows}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
>=stealth,
every left delimiter/.style={xshift=1em},
every right delimiter/.style={xshift=-1em}
]
\matrix (gauss) [
matrix of math nodes,
nodes={minimum width=5em},
left delimiter=[,
right delimiter={]},
row sep=0.5em,
]{
1 & 1 & 1 & 3a \\
1 & 2 & (a+2) & a \\
1 & -(a+1) & -1 & 0 \\
};
\draw (gauss-1-3.north east) -- (gauss-3-3.south east);
\node[drop shadow,fill=orange,draw,rounded corners,draw,rectangle,minimum size=1.5em,inner sep=0pt,node distance=1em,right=of gauss-1-4] (m1) {-1};
\node[drop shadow,fill=orange,draw,rounded corners,draw,rectangle,minimum size=1.5em,inner sep=0pt,node distance=0.5em,right=of m1] (m2) {-1};
\draw[->] (m1) |- ($(gauss-2-4)+(3em,0)$) node[midway,right] {$$};
\draw[->] (m2) |- ($(gauss-3-4)+(3em,0)$) node[midway,right] {$$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please reformat your code above

Comment: I am trying, it looks good on my screen. How can I do?

Comment: Moving nodes around is a bit unspecific. Which nodes do you want to move, and where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example in which the nodes get moved around.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc,chains,matrix,shadows,positioning} %<- added positioning
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
>=stealth,
every left delimiter/.style={xshift=1em},
every right delimiter/.style={xshift=-1em}
]
\matrix (gauss) [
matrix of math nodes,
nodes={minimum width=5em},
left delimiter=[,
right delimiter={]},
row sep=0.5em,
]{
1 & 1 & 1 & 3a \\
1 & 2 & (a+2) & a \\
1 & -(a+1) & -1 & 0 \\
};
\draw (gauss-1-3.north east) -- (gauss-3-3.south east);
% changed the positions in the two nodes below (also using the features of positioning
\node[above=2pt of gauss-1-1,drop shadow,fill=orange,draw,rounded corners,draw,rectangle,minimum size=1.5em,inner sep=0pt] (m1) {-1};
\node[below=2pt of gauss-3-3,drop shadow,fill=orange,draw,rounded corners,draw,rectangle,minimum size=1.5em,inner sep=0pt] (m2) {-1};
\draw[->] (m1) -| ($(gauss-3-2.60)+(0,2pt)$); %<- removed  node[midway,right] {$$} because it wasn't used
\draw[->] (m2) -| ($(gauss-3-4.south)-(0,2pt)$); %<-
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**REVISION**: In my original answer I forgot to remove the `node distance=` directives.

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand it now. I thought I needed to use north-east, south east to move the nodes. Last question, I changed in my test document \node[above=5pt of gauss-1-1,drop to \node[below=5pt of gauss-1-1,drop, and it's at the same heigh as \node[below=2pt of gauss-3-3. What are the ''5pt'' and ''2pt'' for? (sorry about the first comment, I typed enter while I was still writing it, and then couldn't edit it since 5 min had passed)

Comment: @Dovendyr I probably do not understand what you are saying. If I make the replacement of the first node to `\node[below=5pt of gauss-1-1,drop shadow,fill=orange,draw,rounded corners,draw,rectangle,minimum size=1.5em,inner sep=0pt,node distance=1em] (m1) {-1};` I get a very different result, the node then sits just on the left 1 of the second row. The key `below=5pt of gauss-1-1` says that the node is to be placed below the node `gauss-1-1` with the distance being 5pt.

Comment: I meant ''why the distance 5pt looks exactly like distance 2pt?''

Comment: @Dovendyr Because I forgot to remove the `node distance=` directives, see my update. Good catch!